Gegenbauer also called ultraspherical polynomial,in this case why choice of upper param., orthogonal .wrt $(1-x^2)^{\lambda-1/2}$
I paste here from the book Orthogonal Polynomials of Several Variables 2nd ed pp118-9. Here the $Y_n's$ are harmonic homogenous polynomials meaning Laplacian applied to them gives 0 or obey Laplaces eq. with rhs=0. My question is where is he getting the particular value for the upper parameter $\lambda$ here atop the $C_n^\lambda$ which here are Gegenbauer or ultraspherical polynomials. Here he writes the upper as the value $(d\!-\!2)/2$ Why that particular value ? 
For right now i am not concerned with the particular value of $a_n$ nor asking how he derived the particular passage but if anyone also knows that then u can answer that also. Here d is dimension and in $C_n^{(d-2)/2}(x)$ means the wtng function is $(1-x^2)^{d/2-3/2}$. That is different values of n of bottom index should be orthogonal wrt $\int_{-1}^1 (1\!-\!x^2)^{d/2-3/2} C_n^{(d-2)/2}(x)\, C_m^{(d-2)/2}(x)\, dx=0$ if m is ne. n.

One problem here is he uses the double ||...|| notation. This is a notation that should NEVER ever be used as it is ambiguous at the least. For example where he wrote $||Y_n||^{-2}$ NO one has any idea what that means. But i think if you just take $Y_n$ to be orthonormal then can omit that ridiculous ||...|| notation. And where he has $||x||^n$ and $||y||^n$ as long as on surface of unit sphere they can be taken as 1 for otherwise one would have no idea what that ||...|| could possibly mean.
